# How would I allow this HTML syntax inside Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Code:

```
...
31    const App = new Stad (
32        <h1>hello</h1>
33    )
...
```

Comment: You don't. It's invalid JavaScript and is always going to be invalid JavaScript. If you use something like JSX then it might be valid but not otherwise.

Comment: This type of syntax is only available in JSX.

Comment: There are ways to pass a HTML element to JavaScript, but we would need to know more details as to what exactly you want to do. Can you expand your question to include what you are trying to do and what you have tried?

Comment: You can't, at least with that syntax. Have you tried using JSX?

Comment: Just put it in quotations  '<h1>hello</h1>'. Was it that simple or I'm wrong? XD